# ggplot2: How to change the position of a point plot while keep the bar plot in the same position

Tags: r, ggplot2, position

I want to plot the result of a paried t test with a plot containing points, lines and bars, like the plot on the paper (Bellmund, at al. Mapping sequence structure in the human lateral entorhinal cortex. Elife, 8. doi:10.7554/eLife.45333).

See the screenshot of the plot:

[image: See the screenshot of the plot]

In my practise, it is easy to put `geom_point`, `geom_line` and `geom_bar` in the same plot, but the problem comes up when I try to change the positions of the points and lines while remain the bars unchanged.

I tried to use `position_dodge()` in point plot, however, it would move all the elements in the plot. Any ideas? Thanks for help!

```
library(ggplot2)

id <- rep(c(1:29), times = 2)
condition <- c(rep('vector.angle', times = 29), rep('baseline', times = 29))
value <- rnorm(58, mean = 22, sd = 27)
v.angle.gg <- data.frame(id, condition, value)

ggplot(data = v.angle.gg, aes(x = condition, y = value)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), color = "black", size = 1.5, linetype = 14) + 
  stat_summary(fun.y = mean, geom = "bar", aes(x = condition, y = value, fill = condition), 
               width = 0.3, position = position_identity()) + 
  geom_line(aes(group= id), size = 1, color = 'gray') + 
  geom_point(size = 4, position = position_dodge(width= 1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Paired") +
  xlab('Conditions') + ylab('Parameter Estimations') +
  theme(
    title = element_text(size=rel(1.3),face="bold", colour = "black"), 
    axis.line.x = element_line(size = 1, colour = "black"),
    axis.text.x=element_text(size=rel(1.3),face="bold", colour = "black"),
    axis.ticks.x = element_line(size=rel(2), colour = "black"),
    axis.line.y = element_line(size = 1, colour = "black"),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=rel(1.3),face="bold", colour = "black"),
    axis.ticks.y = element_line(size=rel(2), colour = "black"),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    panel.grid = element_blank()
  ) + 
  guides(fill=F,color=F)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question asks for ideas, here is a hack.

Bar plots plot the bars at consecutive integers `x`, in this case `c(1, 2)`. So you need the points and the lines connecting them at `c(1.2, 1.8)`. Now, in the data set column `condition` has the alphabetically larger values first and they will be coerced to factor before plotting. So the new `x` coordinates vector will be subset with `condition` correctly. Not clear?

```
f <- v.angle.gg$condition
f <- c(1.2, 1.8)[as.integer(factor(f))]
```

These are the new coordinates. And they must be set in both `geom_line` and `geom_point`. Makes more sense now? I hope so.
I have simplified the graph so that only the relevant part is plotted.

```
ggplot(data = v.angle.gg, aes(x = condition, y = value)) +
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 0), color = "black", size = 1.5, linetype = 14) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom = "bar", aes(x = condition, y = value, fill = condition), 
               width = 0.3, position = position_identity()) + 
  geom_line(aes(x = f, group= id), size = 1, color = 'gray') + 
  geom_point(aes(x = f), size = 4, position = position_dodge(width= 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you soooo much, that's really make sense! Oh, if it is convient for you, I want to ask why the new columes c(1.2, 1.8) would not generate 2 additional ticks on x-axis?

Comment: @QunjunRoyLiang Good question, wait, let me think.